# Boundedness of entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Let $f$ be entire such that $\forall |z|\geq1$, $|f(z)|\leq e^{-|z|}$. Then how do we prove that $f$ is constant?

Can we map the complement of unit disk conformally onto the complex plane or the unit disk, by virtue of which we may then invoke [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))? Any ideas. Thanks beforehand

Comment: Removed the wholly unnecessary tag liouville-theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $|z| \geq 1$ we have $|f(z)|\leq e^{-|z|} \leq 3 $.

Also, for $|z| \leq 1$, $|f|$ is bounded by a constant $C$, since the unit disc is compact (and $f$ is continuous).

So $|f(z)|\leq \max \{3, C \}$ on all of $\mathbb{C}$. Now Liouville's Theorem does the rest.